# Change route parameter from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have state defined like this:

```
stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            templateUrl: 'views/layout.html',
            url: '/:lang/app',
            resolve: {
                lang: ['$rootScope', '$stateParams', function(rootScope, stateParams){
                    return stateParams.lang;
                }]
            }
        });
```

I have buttons defined for languages, which should navigate to exact same url except of lang parameter should be changed:

```
<a ui-sref="???({ lang: 'en' })"> English </a>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote own directive for this purpose:

```
angular.module('app').directive('uiSrefParams', ['$state', function(state){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.click(function(){
                var params = scope.$eval(attrs['uiSrefParams']);
                state.go(state.$current, params);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

usage:

```
<a ui-sref-params="{ lang: 'en' }"> English </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say, that this feature is already built in the `ui-router`.

1) As documented here:

- [ui-sref](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref)

> `ui-sref='stateName'` - Navigate to state, no params. 'stateName' can be any valid absolute or **relative state**, following the same syntax rules as `$state.go()`

2) And the doc here

- [$state.go(to [, toParams] [, options])](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options) *(older doc, deprecated, but ... so clear)*

> The name of the state that will be transitioned to or a relative state path. If the path starts with **`^`** or **`.`** then it is relative, otherwise it is absolute.
>
> Some examples:

```
$state.go('contact.detail') will go to the 'contact.detail' state
$state.go('^') will go to a parent state.
$state.go('^.sibling') will go to a sibling state.
$state.go('.child.grandchild') will go to a grandchild state.
```

3) And finally there is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cLH9QUNPOQP1VTBdHIzu?p=preview), showing that this feature could be used out of the box:

Having 2 states *(the above plus its 'app.child')* we can use this syntax inside of the 'app' state

```
<a ui-sref=".({ lang: 'en' })"> English </a> 
<a ui-sref=".({ lang: 'cz' })"> Czech </a>
<a ui-sref=".child({ lang: 'en' })"> Child English </a> 
<a ui-sref=".child({ lang: 'cz' })"> Child Czech </a>
```

And this could be used in the child:

```
<a ui-sref=".({ lang: 'en' })"> Sibling English </a> 
<a ui-sref=".({ lang: 'cz' })"> Sibling Czech </a>
```

*Observe the [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/cLH9QUNPOQP1VTBdHIzu?p=preview) to see it in action...*

EXTEND: Check the note from the [ui-sref doc](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref)

> #### A note on relative ui-sref targets:
>
> You can also use relative state paths within `ui-sref`, just like the relative paths passed to `state.go()`. **You just need to be aware that the path is relative to the state that the link lives in, in other words the state that loaded the template containing the link.**

Comment: I tried that solution and it does not work as expected. I had switch button in view of app module. app module has children: app.admin and app.page; when I was at page.admin and clicked anchor with .({ lang: 'en' }) it took me to app module. If I had switch button in app.admin page it would work fine, but I have it in layout

Comment: As my example shows, the relative navigation is working. But I extended the answer with the explanation (coming) from doc, what conditions must be fulfiled. My suggestion would be: try to understand the relative path, use the built in solution, rather then introduce custom directive for the same... but just a suggestion ;)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I agree that built in solution is better to use, but I don't see built in solution for my problem. Your post is very useful anyway